# file_put_contents creates corrupt image

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to parse an RSS feed and download all of the images for each item. I am looping through each item and doing the following to save the image:

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $itemRSS['image']);
$rand = rand(1111, 99999999);
$img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/prod_images/'.$rand.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

There are approximately 100 items in the RSS feed and 100 images are created on the server but when I download them all only a few work, the rest are invalid. They are all jpg's incase you think it's because I'm calling them all .jpg when some might not be.

AHHHH thanks for everyone that commented. I have opened a corrupt one in notepad and get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
The request line contained invalid characters following the protocol string.<P>
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>Apache/1.3.37 Server at www.magicbunny.co.uk Port 80</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Do all these images exist on the server?

Comment: First thing I would check to see if what file_get_contents outputs. It may be that your server has restricted URL access via file_get_contents, in which case you'll need to use cURL

Comment: Can you open the corrupted image in notepad and see if it contains html/text content? A sensible server error message perhaps?

Comment: @JamieBicknell if a few of them work it sounds more like there's some problem with the other end.

Comment: There might be throttling, especially if you don't have a nice user agent? As @SalmanA says, see what the "corrupted" files contain.

Comment: My guess is as @SalmanA suggests you're getting html for some of them (maybe a 404 page).  Either open the corrupt files in a text viewer or try the unix command `file` on them, which will try and identify the file type.

Comment: @therefromhere ah yeh, if URL access was disabled, none would work. Could it be possible that HTACCESS is preventing some images from beging grabbed to prevent leeching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL will have dodgy characters in it - you may need to replace more that " " with %20.
I suggest echoing out the url

```
echo htmlspecialchars($url);
```

for those that are not correct. You can then spot other characters that need replacing.

If you want to do it automatically, break the URL into parts, and urlencode the path (but not the "/"), filename (but not the ".") and then build it back together. But start with the echo first so you know how much work is involved.